# auto refresh javascript without loading whole page

Tags: javascript, highcharts, leaflet, settimeout, page-refresh

I'm working with highcharts and leaflet and I'd like my script to refresh every 10 secondes without refreshing the whole page.
I've succeeded to do so with my highcharts php file but when I do the same with my leaflet script, nothing happens, the map does not appear.
I think the problem is the use of functions but why does it works with highcharts and not with leaflet.

Here's highcharts php file code

```php
<div id="nb_tweets" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<script>

    $(function myFunction() 
    {
        <?php include 'import_nb_tweets.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'import_nb_users.php'; ?>

        $('#nb_tweets').highcharts(
        {
            chart: 
            {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: 
            {
                text: 'Number of tweets trend'
            },
            xAxis: 
            {
                categories: x_axis
            },
            yAxis: 
            {
                title: 
                {
                    text: 'Number of tweets'
                }
            },
            series: 
            [
                {
                    name: 'Precise geolocation',
                    data: nb_precise
                }
                , 
                {
                    name: 'Associated geolocation',
                    data: nb_associated
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'All tweets',
                    data: nb_total
                }
            ]
        });

        setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);

    });

</script>
```

And here's leaflet php file code

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 1300px; height: 650px"></div>
      
<script>
      
    $(function myFunction() {
       
        // Inclusion of database variables
        
            <?php include 'importDB_heat.php'; ?>
            <?php include 'importDB2.php'; ?>
            <?php include 'importDB3.php'; ?>

            
        // Definition of the map variable and the default parameters
        
            var map = new L.map('map', {fullscreenControl: true, fullscreenControlOptions: {position: 'topleft'}}).setView([53.350596, -6.303142], 14);
        
            mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
            
            L.tileLayer
            (
                'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
                {
                    attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
                    maxZoom: 18,
                }
            ).addTo(map);
            
        
        // Definition of separate layers for markers and heat map and for precise and associated geolocation
        
            var heat_layer_place = new L.LayerGroup();
            var heat_layer_precise = new L.LayerGroup();
            
            var precise_layer = new L.LayerGroup();
            var associated_layer = new L.LayerGroup();
        
        
        // Insertion (and defintion) of cluster groups in the markers layers
        
            var markers_precise = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
            markers_precise.addTo(precise_layer);
            
            var markers_associated = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
            markers_associated.addTo(associated_layer);
        
        
        // Loading (and definition) of different icons for every marker layer - 
        
            var blueBird = L.icon({iconUrl: 'twitter_logo_blue.png', iconSize:[45,45], iconAnchor:[23,23], popupAnchor:[0,-19]});
            var redBird = L.icon({iconUrl: 'twitter_logo_red.png', iconSize:[40,40], iconAnchor:[23,23], popupAnchor:[0,-19]});
            
        
        // Insertion of heat layers on the map
        
            var heat_place = L.heatLayer(quakePoints_place,{radius: <?php include 'par_map_rad.php'; ?>, blur: <?php include 'par_map_blur.php'; ?>, maxZoom: <?php include 'par_map_maxzoom.php'; ?>, }).addTo(map).addTo(heat_layer_place);
            var heat_precise = L.heatLayer(quakePoints_precise,{radius: <?php include 'par_map_rad.php'; ?>, blur: <?php include 'par_map_blur.php'; ?>, maxZoom: <?php include 'par_map_maxzoom.php'; ?>, }).addTo(map).addTo(heat_layer_precise);
        
        
        // Implementation (and insertion) of markers layers on the map
        
            var nb_points = tweet_position.length;
            
            for (var iter = 0; iter < nb_points; iter++) 
            {
                markers_precise.addLayer(L.marker(tweet_position[iter],{title: tile_precise[iter], opacity: <?php include 'par_map_precise_op.php'; ?>, icon: blueBird}).bindPopup(texte_precise[iter]));
            }
            
            var nb_points_bis = tweet_place.length;
            
            for (var iter = 0; iter < nb_points_bis; iter++) 
            {
                markers_associated.addLayer(L.marker(tweet_place[iter],{title: tile_place[iter], opacity: <?php include 'par_map_associated_op.php'; ?>, icon: redBird}).bindPopup(texte_place[iter]));
            }
            
            map.addLayer(markers_precise);
            map.addLayer(markers_associated);
            
        
        // Definition (and insertion) of basic optional layers for the map
        
            var osmLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
            var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors';
            var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib});
            
            var thunLink = '<a href="http://thunderforest.com/">Thunderforest</a>';
            var landUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var thunAttrib = '&copy; '+osmLink+' Contributors & '+thunLink;
            var landMap = L.tileLayer(landUrl, {attribution: thunAttrib});
            
            var EWI = '<a href="http://www.esri.com/">Esri</a>';
            var EWIUrl = 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}';
            var EWIAttrib = '&copy; '+ EWI +'i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community';
            var EWIMap = L.tileLayer(EWIUrl, {attribution: EWIAttrib});
            
            var transport = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
            var transportUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var translink = '<a href="http://thunderforest.com/">Thunderforest</a>';
            var transportAttrib = '&copy; '+ transport +' Contributors & '+translink;
            var transportMap = L.tileLayer(transportUrl, {attribution: transportAttrib});
        
            var baseLayers = {"OSM Mapnik": osmMap,"Landscape": landMap, "Esri World Imagery": EWIMap, "Transport": transportMap};
            var overlays = {"Tweet location: precise geolocation": precise_layer, "Tweet location: associated geolocation": associated_layer, "Tweet density: associated geolocation": heat_layer_place, "Tweet density: precise geolocation": heat_layer_precise};
            L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlays).addTo(map);
            
            
        // Restriction of the result area of the search tool
            
            var southWest = L.latLng(<?php include 'par_dublin_lat_SW.php'; ?>, <?php include 'par_dublin_long_SW.php'; ?>);
            var northEast = L.latLng(<?php include 'par_dublin_lat_NE.php'; ?>, <?php include 'par_dublin_long_NE.php'; ?>);
            var boundsOSM = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
            var optionsOSM = {bounds: boundsOSM};
            
        
        // Insertion of the place search tool
        
            var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.OSMGeocoder(optionsOSM);
            map.addControl(osmGeocoder);
          
            setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);

    });
            
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting any sort of JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 2):

This is what AJAX/XHR requests are made for. With it you can fetch data in the background and update your highcharts/leaflet with it. Here's an example of what you can do with AJAX/XHR:

Starting off with a simple map and a group to store markers in:

```
var map = L.map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0,
    'layers': [
         L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
             'attribution': 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
         })
    ]
});

var group = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
```

Using jQuery's $.getJSON (A function to preform XHR GET requests with JSON data) you can request data in the background and use it in your current map. I'll explain through out the code in comments:

```
// Function for handling data
function handle(response) {
  // Empty the current layergroup
  group.clearLayers();
  // Loop over the newly retreived array
  response.forEach(function(value) {
    // Add new marker to the group
    group.addLayer(new L.Marker(value));
  });
}

// Function for requesting new data
function request() {
  // Fetch url and execute handle function on success
  $.getJSON('coordinates.json', handle);
}

// Immediately request new data
request();
// Request new data every ten seconds
setInterval(request, 10000);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qasIC2?p=preview (mind, it requests the same data over and over again so the marker positions don't actually change but i've add some console messages so that you can verify it works) You can easily adapt this concept to what you are trying to do.